# Find two elements in a list, order them by their occurence

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that takes a list and two elements that can possibly be contained in the list. The function should return the two elements in a structure that sorts them by their occurrence in the list.

So, for number we'd have something like this:

```
xs = [4,6,3,2,1,8]
f (3,1) --> (Just 3, Just 1)
f (1,3) --> (Just 3, Just 1)
f (9,1) --> (Just 1, Nothing)
f (9,9) --> (Nothing, Nothing)
```

and so on..

I used tuples up there since I'm actually only interested in those two values instead of an arbitrary number. But if there are reasons, modeling it as list would be ok as well.

Anyways, here's the function I came up with:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> (a, a) -> (Maybe a, Maybe a) 
f xs (a, b) = foldl g (Nothing, Nothing) xs  where
  g (Nothing, Nothing) x | x == a            = (Just a, Nothing)
  g (Nothing, Nothing) x | x == b            = (Just b, Nothing)
  g (Just a', Nothing) x | a' == a && x == b = (Just a, Just b)
  g (Just b', Nothing) x | b' == b && x == a = (Just b, Just a)
  g m x = m
```

Its working, but I think it's quite a lot of pattern matching in there, it's sort of error-prone. So, does anybody have a better abstraction for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decrease number of pattern matchings then it's better to never pass pair `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` recursively and pattern match on it. You can just split your function into two recursive functions where first functions finds first element and calls second function with the other. This can be done like this:

```
f :: Eq a => (a, a) -> [a] -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
f (a, b) = goFirst
  where
    goFirst []    = (Nothing, Nothing)
    goFirst (x:xs)
      | x == a    = (Just a, goSecond b xs)
      | x == b    = (Just b, goSecond a xs)
      | otherwise = goFirst xs

    goSecond _ [] = Nothing
    goSecond y (x:xs)
      | x == y    = Just y
      | otherwise = goSecond y xs
```

This is not so short and elegant as you may want but it's readable, fast (I want to add that you should never ever use `foldl` function) and less error-prone.

If you're looking for some abstractions, you may look at [`First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) monoid with pair monoid. Using monoid instance for `First` data type you can start with something like this:

```
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)
import Data.Monoid    (First (..), mconcat)

g :: Eq a => (a, a) -> [a] -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
g (a, b) = bimap getFirst getFirst . mconcat . map fMapper
  where
    fMapper x
      | x == a    = (First (Just a), mempty)
      | x == b    = (mempty, First (Just b))
      | otherwise = mempty
```

Though this function doesn't do exactly what you want:

```
ghci> let xs = [4,6,3,2,1,8]
ghci> g (3, 1) xs
(Just 3,Just 1)
ghci> g (1, 3) xs
(Just 1,Just 3)
```

To achieve initial goal with this approach you can add indices to each element and then sort pairs under `First` by indices but this solution is scary and ugly. Using `First` monoid is tempting but I don't know how it can be used here elegantly.

But you can combine ideas from first and second solutions:

```
import Data.Bool   (bool)
import Data.Monoid (First (..))

h :: Eq a => (a, a) -> [a] -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
h (a, b) = goFirst
  where
    goFirst []    = (Nothing, Nothing)
    goFirst (x:xs)
      | x == a    = (Just a, goSecond b xs)
      | x == b    = (Just b, goSecond a xs)
      | otherwise = goFirst xs

    goSecond y = getFirst . foldMap (bool mempty (First (Just y)) . (== y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one possible solution with lists, of the following type:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
```

I’ll call the list to be searched the `haystack` and the elements to search for the `needles`. First, we can search the `haystack` for each `needle` and return a pair of the value and the index where it was found, if any, using `findIndex`:

```
findIndices needles haystack =
  [ (needle, findIndex (== needle) haystack)
  | needle <- needles
  ]

findIndices [1, 3] xs == [(1, Just 4), (3, Just 2)]
```

(Note that this always uses the index of the *first* occurrence—I’m not sure if that’s what you want. You can extend this into a fold that removes each occurrence as it’s found.)

Then sort this list by the index:

```
sortBy (comparing snd) [(1, Just 4), (3, Just 2)]
==
[(3, Just 2), (1, Just 4)]
```

And finally extract the value for each index that was actually present, using `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a`:

```
[value <$ mIndex | (value, mIndex) <- [(3, Just 2), (1, Just 4)]]
==
[Just 3, Just 1]
```

(`x <$ f` is equivalent to `const x <$> f`.)

But when we try this on an input where some elements aren’t found, we get the wrong result, where the `Nothing`s come at the beginning rather than the end:

```
findIndices [9, 1] xs == [(9, Nothing), (1, Just 4)]

sortBy (comparing snd) [(9, Nothing), (1, Just 4)]
==
[(9, Nothing), (1, Just 4)]
```

This is because `Nothing` is considered less than any `Just` value. Since we want the opposite, we can reverse the sort order of the `Maybe` using the `Down` newtype from `Data.Ord`, by passing `Down . snd` instead of `snd` as the comparator:

```
sortBy (comparing (Down . snd)) [(9, Nothing), (1, Just 4)]
==
[(1, Just 4), (9, Nothing)]
```

But this *also* reverses the sort order of the indices themselves, which we don’t want:

```
sortBy (comparing (Down . snd)) [(1, Just 4), (3, Just 2)]
==
[(1, Just 4), (3, Just 2)]
```

So we can just add another `Down` around the indices:

```
findIndices needles haystack =
  [ (needle, Down <$> findIndex (== needle) haystack)
  | needle <- needles
  ]

sortBy (comparing Down) [Just (Down 2), Nothing, Just (Down 1)]
==
[Just (Down 1), Just (Down 2), Nothing]

sortBy (comparing (Down . snd))
  [(1, Down (Just 4)), (3, Down (Just 2))]
==
[(3, Down (Just 2)), (1, Down (Just 4))]
```

And finally put it all together:

```
f :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
f needles haystack =
  [ value <$ index
  | (value, index) <- sortBy (comparing (Down . snd))
    [ (needle, Down <$> findIndex (== needle) haystack)
    | needle <- needles
    ]
  ]

f [1, 3] xs == [Just 3, Just 1]
f [3, 1] xs == [Just 3, Just 1]
f [1, 9] xs == [Just 1, Nothing]
f [9, 9] xs == [Nothing, Nothing]
```

Or, without list comprehensions and with shorter names:

```
f :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
f ns hs
  = map (\ (v, i) -> v <$ i)
  $ sortBy (comparing (Down . snd))
  $ map (\ n -> (n, Down <$> findIndex (== n) hs)) ns
```

`\ (v, i) -> v <$ i` can also be written as `uncurry (<$)`, but that might be a bit cryptic if you’re not accustomed to point-free style. In addition, if you don’t care about the `Nothing`s, you can use `mapMaybe` instead of `map`, changing the return type from `[Maybe a]` to just `[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much better you will think these are, but you can do some things making more use of list functions.

I initially thought of filtering out the irrelevant
items first, and grouping:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> (a,a) -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
f xs (a, b) =
  case (map head . group . filter (`elem` [a,b])) xs of
    [] -> (Nothing, Nothing)
    [c] -> (Just c, Nothing)
    (c:d:_) -> (Just c, Just d)
```

But this doesn't do the same as your implementation on, for example,
`f [8,9,9] (9,9)`, so you'd need to special-case that if it's a case
you care about.

Another way is with `dropWhile`:

```
f' :: Eq a => [a] -> (a,a) -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
f' xs (a, b) =
  case dropWhile (`notElem` [a, b]) xs of
    [] -> (Nothing, Nothing)
    (y:ys) -> (Just y, next)
      where
        next = case dropWhile (/=other) ys of
                 [] -> Nothing
                 (z:_) -> Just z
        other = if y == a then b else a
```

And the inner case is really just a `find` so it can be simplified a
little more:

```
f'' :: Eq a => [a] -> (a,a) -> (Maybe a, Maybe a)
f'' xs (a, b) =
  case dropWhile (`notElem` [a, b]) xs of
    [] -> (Nothing, Nothing)
    (y:ys) -> (Just y, find (==other) ys)
      where
        other = if y == a then b else a
```

Note: these functions never return a result of the form `(Nothing, Just _)`.  This suggests that a return type of `Maybe (a, Maybe a)`
might be better.  Or a custom type like `None | One a | Two a a`.

Alternatively, we could generalize to a list version which allows as
many target values as you like.  It makes a nice unfold:

```
f''' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
f''' xs ts = unfoldr g (xs, ts)
  where
    g (ys, us) = case dropWhile (`notElem` us) ys of
                   [] -> Nothing
                   (z:zs) -> Just (z, (zs, delete z us))
```

Which works like this:

```
λ> f''' [4,2,5,3,1] [1,2,3]
[2,3,1]
λ> f''' [4,2,5,3,1] [1,2,6]
[2,1]
λ> f''' [7,9,8,9] [9,9]
[9,9]
```

I'm almost reinventing `intersect` here but not quite.  It has the behaviour we want of preserving the order from the first list, but it isn't the same on duplicates - e.g. `intersect [4,2,2,5] [1,2]` is `[2,2]`.